# Convert string of dynamic size to ints with stringstream

Tags: c++, gcc, std

I'm trying to add int values to a vector, by converting a user-given string with stringstream. The user gives the data like this: 1,5,6,7,4 so I'll never know exactlyhow many int there will be.

Right now I only get the first entered numbers. The rest is ignored.
This is what I kind of want:

```
stringstream ss;
int tmpInt;
string data;

cout << "Enter data: (1,2,3,4 etc.)";
getline(cin, data);

ss.str(data);

while(ss >> tmpInt)
{
    myList.addValue(tmpInt);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you `ignore` the commas:

```
while(ss >> tmpInt)
{
    myList.addValue(tmpInt);
    ss.ignore();
}
```

Currently, the extraction will attempt to read an integer, find that there's a comma, and stick the stream in a failed state.

Alternatively, if you want to check whether the character is actually a comma (for the sake of input validation), you could do:

```
while(ss >> tmpInt)
{
    myList.addValue(tmpInt);
    if (ss.get() != ',') break;
}
```

Comment: You can tell the `ignore()` method to specifically ignore commas, using `ss.ignore(n, ',')`, where `n` is a sufficiently large number of characters to skip, until the `','` is reached

Comment: My god you were quick! I also tried doing this on the data string: replace(choice.begin(), choice.end(), ',', ' '); and that seems to work as well. What is the most kosher thing to do here?

Comment: @Tophe I wouldn't do the replacement. You should figure out exactly what you consider to be valid input and validate accurately. Using your replace method, they may also input `1   , 2  3 4,5`. Do you want that?

Comment: As a "sufficently large number" in the comment by @naxchange, usually `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is used.

Comment: @naxchange Yes, it depends exactly what Tophe considers to be valid input. If you did that, it would then accept `1woot,2,3   ,  4,5`.

Comment: Using `peek` and `get` in a loop while the peeked character is not a digit might work as well, especially if the input is not uniformly formatted.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yep, there are lots of ways to do this. I find the I/O library to be badly designed and confusing. The core I/O library should have just dealt with bytes (or some abstraction over characters) and then parsers should have been built over the top. But instead we have a mishmash of extraction functions that often do something a little weird.